# HTML page shows nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap CSS and JS but nothing is being displayed in the page. 
Here is the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <title>Chat @ null</title>
        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="bootstrap.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='d-flex btn-group'>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary w-100'>Hello</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-success w-100'>Welcome</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger w-100'>CSS</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary w-100'>BootStrap</a>
        </div>
        <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: close <script src="bootstrap.js">... </script>

Comment: page loads successfully when i omit the script tag

Comment: close script tag first..your closing script tag is missing

Comment: after closing the script tag, js doesn't works

Comment: @GauravGoswami In what way doesn't the script work after correcting the error?

Comment: alert message doesn't close

Comment: You missed to include jquery(<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>) and close script tag for bootstrap

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @GauravGoswami  check my snippet alert box is closing correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the file is not included correctly!..give correct path for css and js..or use CDN instead

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <title>Chat @ null</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>    
   <body>
      <div class = 'd-flex btn-group' >
      <a href = '#'
    class = 'btn btn-primary w-100' > Hello </a>
     <a href = '#'
    class = 'btn btn-success w-100' > Welcome </a> <a href = '#'
    class = 'btn btn-danger w-100' > CSS </a> <a href = '#'
    class = 'btn btn-primary w-100' > BootStrap </a> </div> <div class = 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible' >
      <a href = '#'
    class='close'
    data-dismiss = 'alert'
    aria-label = 'close' >&times; </a> <strong > Success! < /strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action. </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: He may have downloaded the bootstrap.

Comment: @vincent-d yeah..that's why I have written 'give correct path' or use cdn

Answer (score 0):

try below. There is a syntax error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <title>Chat @ null</title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='d-flex btn-group'>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary w-100'>Hello</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-success w-100'>Welcome</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger w-100'>CSS</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary w-100'>BootStrap</a>
        </div>
        <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to close the `<script>` tag,
change `<script src="bootstrap.js">` to `<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

you need to format your code correctly and end the script tag first

try below code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <title>Chat @ null</title>
  <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
  
</head> 
<body>
      <div class="d-flex btn-group">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Hello</a> 
        <a href = "#" class = "btn btn-success w-100">Welcome</a>
        
      </div>  
      <div class = "alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
        <a href = "#" class = "close" data-dismiss = "alert" aria-label="close"> & times; </a> <strong> Success! </strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
      </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <title>Chat @ null</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='d-flex btn-group'>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary w-100'>Hello</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-success w-100'>Welcome</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-danger w-100'>CSS</a>
            <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary w-100'>BootStrap</a>
        </div>
        <div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
            <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
            <strong>Success!</strong> This alert box could indicate a successful or positive action.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```